# dnn 7 custom module pass user info to module

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am building a custom module that will display customer information from a MS SQL database on a page. I need to pass a custom profile field created in DNN(CustNumber) using c# to a custom module so I can pull information depending on who logs in to a SQL query. Please help. Thanks

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to load the User Information for the logged in user. Assuming the Control of your module inherits from PortalModuleBase you have access to the UserID and UserInfo objects so you can get profile properties easily.

```
var uc = new UserController();
var ui = uc.GetUser(PortalId, UserId);

var propertyValue = ui.Profile.GetPropertyValue("PropertyName");
```

Comment: Thank for the response Chris. I'm using your DNN 7 C# template for the module. I'll give this a try. Thank you for your help.